# Android 9 armeabi-v7 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install an app with an armeabi-v7a native library on my emulator. The old arm system images run really slowly in the emulator. According to the Emulator release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#30-0-0) One can use any image of android version 9 and 11 to run armeabi-v7a. However after downloading `Intel x86 atom` image of android version 9 via the SDK manager, I am still not able to install/debug my app on the emulator. Is there anything else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Google stopped releasing arm images from API 26 (so latest arm  image is Android 7.1.1)

Comment: @feridok please read the link I mentioned in my post, it says they added support for arm, in the newer x86 image - "x86: Includes both x86 and ARMv7 ABIs.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting a system image for AVD, navigate to "x86 images" and select the one that says Android 9.0 (Google x86_ARM). Or use any R images as this announcement suggests: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no Android 9.0 (Google x86_ARM) whatsoever listed (at least in the latest Android Studio (as of today).